# Check mutation of a gene

Tags: sam, vcf

[image]
Hi all, I am checking if a gene which around 50k base pairs has mutation. So is that a variant from A to G? Would you please tell me how to do so? Thank you so much!

The reference sequence from GRCh38, sequenced using Illumina technology.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146872/discussion-on-question-by-chris-check-mutation-of-a-gene); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a diploid genome, this looks like it could be a heterozygous variant (i.e. A is present on one chromosome, and G is present on the other chromosome).